# Reactjs: How to add delete icon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my project, there is an input field to add email values. Here added chips to convert the added items to tags. but I don't know how to add the "X" delete button inside each tag

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import "./styles.css";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
    value: "",
    error: null,

  };

  handleKeyDown = evt => {
    if (["Enter", "Tab", ","].includes(evt.key)) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      var value = this.state.value.trim();

      if (value && this.isValid(value)) {
        this.setState({
          items: [...this.state.items, this.state.value],
          value: ""
        });
      }
    }
  };

  handleChange = evt => {
    this.setState({
      value: evt.target.value,
      error: null
    });
  };

  handleDelete = (item) => {
    console.log("delete")
    
  };
  
  handleItemEdit = item =>{
      const result = this.state.items.filter(values=>values!==item)
      this.setState({
        value: item,
        error: null,
        items: result
      });
  }

  handlePaste = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var paste = evt.clipboardData.getData("text");
    var emails = paste.match(/[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/g);

    if (emails) {
      var toBeAdded = emails.filter(email => !this.isInList(email));

      this.setState({
        items: [...this.state.items, ...toBeAdded]
      });
    }
  };

  isValid(email) {
    let error = null;

    if (this.isInList(email)) {
      error = `${email} has already been added.`;
    }

    if (!this.isEmail(email)) {
      error = `${email} is not a valid email address.`;
    }

    if (error) {
      this.setState({ error });

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  isInList(email) {
    return this.state.items.includes(email);
  }

  isEmail(email) {
    return /[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/.test(email);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        
        <TextField
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: this.state.items.map(item => (
            <Chip
              key={item}
              tabIndex={-1}
              label={item}
              onDelete={this.handleDelete(item)}
            />
          )),
        }}
          ref={this.state.items}
          className={"input " + (this.state.error && " has-error")}
          value={this.state.value}
          placeholder="Type or paste email addresses and press `Enter`..."
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onPaste={this.handlePaste}
        />

        {this.state.error && <p className="error">{this.state.error}</p>}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image]

I am a beginner in reactjs. I don't know if there is any problem while using chips component so please give me valuable solutions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Material-UI` library you are using makes this very easy.
Their components behave differently based on the types of props you provide them with.

In the case of `<Chip>`, if you pass an `onDelete` method, it should automatically show the "X" at the end.

However, since you already did that, it should work.
My guess here is that maybe it doesn't register properly due to the way you pass the function.

In React, when passing function to components, etc.. we should pass them as callbacks, instead of calling them directly.

**Example:**

```
<Chip
   // Other props...
   onDelete={() => this.handleDelete(item)}
/>
```

Let me know if this works.

**Refs:**

- https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html
- https://mui.com/material-ui/react-chip/

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add icon

Way 1 u can use material ui icons to
add  icon
Way 2 u can use bootstrap 5 to add icon

By way 2 the steps are

Step 1 Keep the cdn in the  head part in  index.html

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Step 2 is to add your icon where we want

```
<i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
```